# Android Develop login session

Tags: php, android, database, session

I need to develop an Android App that interacts with a server (db + php scripts). Firstly the App requests to the user “username” and “password” and then call a php script (for example Login.php) that return true or false, respectively if the data are correct or not. If they are correct, application interacts with the other php script (The scripts can ins/delete/check data) and every time app calls a script, it sends also the username and password, because every script firstly check if they are correct, and if so it does the specific job.

My question is:
Is this method correct?
What is the best way to check the session of the user between android app and a set of php script (that interact with a DB)?

Thank you very much

Comment: There are 3 different things
1)- Php Session
2)- Android App Session
3)- Android and Php session (sync session) i.e app and server having same session.
What you want to achieve ??
Session for android app or you want user will logged in until Php session is available ?

Comment: you can try android shared preferences to check session. you can store user id in this preference and send this id to every apis (php scripts)